# What is the dog in "Hector and the Search for Happiness" used for?

Tags: film-techniques, screenwriter

In "Hector and the search for Happiness", there is a dog that Hector keeps referring to, throughout the movie. The dog has no name, and doesn't appear to be real (either Hector's imagination or a memory from his childhood). And is only used in certain situations, like Hector talking to himself or perhaps as a means of talking indirectly to the audience.

My question is kind of a two-parter; what is this mechanic called, and what is it used for?

Answer (score -1):

[According to this review](https://thedissolve.com/reviews/1084-hector-and-the-search-for-happiness/):

> And to break up the action, **Hector’s inner child makes the occasional appearance, alongside his childhood dog.**
>
> The ultimate point is clear: **Hector needs to grow up.** He’s yet another in the ranks of 21st-century cinematic man-children making a belated journey to maturity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This kind of answers the question, But I am more asking about the technique/mechanic this is in the movie (i.e. a tool that the scriptwriter uses for a particular effect on the audience/on the movie itself), rather than what it is in the storyline.

Comment: I may need to word the question a little differently, if that is unclear.

Comment: @ben I answered the question in the title of your question. Considering you don't even know the function of the scenes, how can you then try to find a name for such a technique (if there even is one)?